# Changing the content of a form from outside?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a form called `MyForm`, and I want to edit it's properties in the middle of the program's execution, from outside of the class itself.

Here's what I got:

```
static void Main()
{
    MyForm main = new MyForm();
    main.ShowDialog();
    main.Text = "Hello";
}
```

However, it seems like `ShowDialog()` just freezes the program until I close the form, so `main.Text = "Hello";` won't be executed until I close the form.

I've also tried using `main.Show()` but it just closes the form after I've executed all the code in my `Main()` function, so the text `"Hello"` will only flash quickly.

I would need it so that I can have the form open at all times and change it's controls in the middle of the program's execution, from outside of the class itself.

How can I achieve this? Should I run the form in a different thread or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't know what is your specific scenario. Perhaps my solution is good for you, but if it isn't, please, try to tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve.

```
static void Main()
{
    var main = new MyForm();
    //Initialize a new thread with the `DoSomething()` method
    //and pass the form as a parameter
    var thread = new Thread(() => DoSomething(main)) {IsBackground = true};
    thread.Start();
    main.ShowDialog();
}

static void DoSomething(MyForm main) {
    //Update the form title
    main.Text = "Hello";
    //Wait one second
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    //Update the form title again
    main.Text = "World";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple questions here, you should try to focus on one at a time, so let me highlight the questions.

1. Why does my program close when Main exits?
2. How can I avoid "freezing" the program when showing a form?
3. How can I access the contents of a form from elsewhere?

Answers:

1. That's the design of how the lifetime of a program is. When the main thread (running the Main method) terminates, the program closes. Any open forms are closed in the process. Solution is to not allow Main to exit, typically by using `Application.Run(main);` in your case, showing the form and waiting for it to close.
2. You use `Show` and not `ShowDialog`, but since you have no other form keeping the program open, your program closes. Show returns after showing the form, returning to whatever the program was doing. In your case, the program has nothing left to do, so it terminates.
3. You need to store a reference to your form somewhere the rest of your program can access it, you can use a static field/property somewhere, or you can pass the form around to the various parts that need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already knew all this and this doesn't answer my question one bit. Good answer, but on the wrong question. I've made my question bit more clear, maybe you'd understand my problem better now.

Comment: Seems like a pretty solid answer to me.